# text display problem-Juno

Tags: gala

Have a pulsating ghost image problem with text. The behavior is as if the baseline or bounding box translation of a group of text, not a full line, nor necessarily a singular location, has a rounding error. This causes the text group to try and display in 2, sometimes 3 locations at once, mostly one line below, occasionally above. the 2,3 images vary in intensity due to not fully committed to a location, number of tries as to where it displays. It seems to be all applications. Can create by pgup, pgdn, mouse scrolling, but arrow key scrolling appears to be immune. Cannot report to elementary github, tried 2 different OSes, different browsers.
machine: Ryzen 2400g, ASRock Fatal1ty B450 Gaming-ITX, HyperX Alloy Elite keyboard, Dell mouse, 55" RCA TV as monitor. Occurred Juno normal release (new install) and updated linux 4.20 kernel, with updated mesa. Tried mouse plugged in at different ports also.